# Rails query outputting all table column data, just want image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the following rails query:

```
@related_products = @taxon.product.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count)).limit(7)
```

And then I'm trying to output the images with this:

```
    <ul class="related_products_list">
         <%= @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
         <li class="related_products_item"><%= link_to large_image(related_product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "related_products_image"), url_for(related_product) %></li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
```

But when I output the image its displaying the image along with a total dump of all table data for each product. Any ideas why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
```

to this:

```
<% @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
```

Explanation: `<%=` renders its content so the content of `@related_products` gets inserted into the page.

Comment: Sheesh. I'm sorry. I don't know how I missed that. I appreciate it.